# Can I calculate the area of a intersection polygon from shape file in R?

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, weather

I have two shape files, one with municipality data and one with precipitation data. The precipitation data is in the form of square boxes with standard dimension while munipilaties have their standard weird shapes.

I am using R and I merged the two shape files using the st_intersection function. Now I want to divide the precipitation data, within each square box, in proportion to the area of the municipality that actually fall into the square box.

This means that if in a square there are 3 municipalities, I need to calculate the area of the municipalities within that box and allocate the total precipitation of the square in proportion to the area covered by the three municipalities.

I am struggling to obtain a working result, any help would be great!
Thanks in advance!

I tried to calculate the area of each municipality within each box with this code but results seems to be wrong

```
Area <- intersected_data %>% 
  mutate(area = st_area(.) %>% as.numeric())
```

Comment: Hi Flavio, and welcome!  **Please provide a sample of your `intersected_data` by pasting the output from `dput(head(intersected_data, n = 10))`.**  This is known as a "reproducible example", or simply "reprex".  Another word of advice: when you use `.` in a workflow chained by `%>%`, that `.` refers to the entire _object_ from the previous step.  So when you write `st_area(.)`, you are really writing `st_area(intersected_data)`.  Is that what you really meant to do?